# How to do multicolumns footnotes for pages of a book?

Tags: footnotes, multicolumn, book-design

I am trying to typeset books about theology, but the books have many footnotes
for page. So, I want to insert the footnotes in columns, in the base of page (on footer),
like the book in this address (for example, pages 6 and 7 of this book):

https://archive.org/details/institutesofchris02calv/page/6/mode/2up

I have tried many solutions, but I couldn't make it. How to do it?

Please, I am sorry by my English.

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}
\usepackage{multicol}

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

\rmfamily
\parskip 0in
\headsep 0.3cm
\footskip 0cm

%These are in another files.
\include{Capa}
\include{PrefacioTradutor}
\include{PrefacioAutor}

%This is for configure footnotes markers and fonts.
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{(\textit{\alph{footnote}})}
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@makefnmark{{{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}\ }%
%\makeatother
%\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have edited and extended my answer, particularly with questions for how you think your desired capabilities should the presented to the user. --- GOM

Answer (score 1):

It would have been very helpful if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass`   to `\end{document}`) that we could compile that showed your problem. Your MWE as posted had no `\footnote`s

The `memoir` class (a superset of the `book` class provides for normal footnotes (`\plainfootnotes`), footnotes in two columns (`\twocolumnfootnotes`), in three columns (`threecolumnfootnotes`) and all together as a single paragraph (`\paragraphfootnotes`)

**EDIT**

Here is an example:

```
% colfootnotesprob.tex SE 634234

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

Text\footnote{First footnote}

%\twocolumnfootnotes
\threecolumnfootnotes
Text\footnote{Second footnote}

Text\footnote{Third footnote}

Text\footnote{Another footnote}

Text\footnote{And yet another longer footnote}

\plainfootnotes
Text\footnote{Fourth footnote}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However in regard to your comment about having something like `multicols` for footnotes I think that would be very difficult. What sort of user interface would you think would be appropriate? How would you specify for each individual footnote the number of multicols it should fit into. Group all footnotes of a similar style together irrespective of their ordering in the text, or what? I can imagine many other user interface desires.

Comment: Yes, I understood. I am sorry because of my code, but I don't know how to solve the problem anyway. The most near that I have coming is using the package 'footmisc', with the option 'para', but it isn't exactly what I need. Your solution is good, but some pages will have four columns, for example. There's a limitation of number of footnotes by line. It would be better if had some solution to specify how many columns of footnotes by line I need, like the 'multicol' package for paragraphs, can you understand me? Anyway, thanks a lot by your attention and patience!
:)

Comment: For a book with many very short footnotes, and some longer ones, I've used `bigfoot` with `para` style, adding some `hspace` at the end of the footnote (e.g. `\newcommand{\parafootnote}[1]{\footnote{#1\hspace*{2em}}`). They are not columns, but the space helps the reader to identify each footnote.